# How to do `head` and `tail` on null-delimited input in bash?

Tags: text-processing, find, xargs, tail, head

`find` command can output names of files as a null-delimited strings (if `-print0` is provided), and `xargs` can consume them with `-0` option turned on. But in between, it's hard to manipulate that collection of files - `sort` command has `-z` switch, that makes it possible to sort those files, but `head` and `tail` don't have them.

How can I do `head` and `tail` on those null-delimited inputs in a convenient way? (I can always create a short & slow ruby script, but I hope that there could be a better way)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

GNU `head` and `tail` since coreutils version 8.25 have a `-z` option for that.

With older versions or for non-GNU systems, you can try and swap `\0` and `\n`:

```
find ... -print0 |
  tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
  head |
  tr '\0\n' '\n\0'
```

Note that some `head` implementations can't cope with NUL characters (and they're not required to by POSIX), but where find supports `-print0`, `head` and text utilities generally support NUL characters.

You can also use a function to wrap any command between the two `tr`s:

```
nul_terminated() {
  tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | "$@" | tr '\0\n' '\n\0'
}

find ... -print0 | nul_terminated tail -n 12 | xargs -r0 ...
```

Keep in mind that under `nul_terminated`, a `\0` means a newline character. So for instance, to replace `\n` with `_`:

```
find . -depth -name $'*\n*' -print0 | nul_terminated sed '
  p;h;s,.*/,,;s/\x0/_/g;H;g;s,[^/]*\n,,' | xargs -r0n2 mv
```

(`\x0` being also a GNU extension).

If you need to run more than one *filtering* command, you can do:

```
find ... -print0 |
  nul_terminated cmd1 |
  nul_terminated cmd2 | xargs -r0 ...
```

But that means running a few redundant `tr` commands. Alternatively, you can run:

```
find ... -print0 | nul_terminated eval 'cmd1 | cmd2' | xargs -r0 ...
```

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the primary reason¹ for using `\x0` instead of `\n` to delimit the values? (¹ so you can cope with values that might contain `\n`)

Comment: @Thedward, no, on the contrary `-print0 | tr '\n\0' '\0\n'` has _lines_ representing the file paths where newline characters in them have been converted to `\0`. So, if you take the first line with `head -n 1` and convert the `\0`s back to newlines with `tr '\0\n' '\n\0'` again, you've got the first file path NUL-delimited with its embedded newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

On an older system of mine, `grep` supported null delimited input, so I did this as a replacement for `head --zero-terminated -n 3` to obtain the 3 newest files:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" | sort -zrn | grep -zm 3 ""
```

A combination of `sort` and `grep` will then allow a replacement for `tail` to obtain the 3rd newest file:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" | sort -zrn | grep -zm 3 "" | sort -zn | grep -zm 1 ""
```

Filename only:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" | sort -zrn | grep -zm 3 "" | sort -zn | grep -zPom 1 "(?s)/.*"
```

Sadly `-o` (only-matching) disables the zero delimited output (bug!?), which was enabled through `-z` and returns the filename with an ending new line, which disallows further piping

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" | sort -zrn | grep -zm 3 "" | sort -zn | grep -zPom 1 "(?s)/.*" | xargs -0 ls -l
ls: cannot access /te
st
: No such file or directory
```

This can be solved by using `read`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" | sort -zrn | grep -zm 3 "" | sort -zn | { IFS=" " read -rd '' mtime file && echo -en "$file\0"; } | xargs -0 -n1 ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 24 17:46 ./te?st
```

(`ls -t` returns a question mark for the new line character in the filename as expected)

Or another example how to obtain the 100 oldest files in the current dir:

```
find /tmp/test -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" | sort -zn | grep -zm 10 "" | { while IFS=" " read -rd '' mtime file; do echo -en "$file\0"; done; } | xargs -0 -n1 ls -bl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 23 14:32 /tmp/test/foo\ baz.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 26 10:43 /tmp/test/foo\nbar\ baz.txt
...
```

Comment: `-printf '%T@/%p\0' | sort -zrn | IFS=/ read -rd '' mtime file` would make more sense. By using `echo -e`, you're defeating the purpose of using NUL-delimited  records. Use `printf '%s\0' "$file"`. Using a shell loop is going to be less efficient than using the couple of `tr`s that can be used to transform from/to a format that  older GNU `cut`/`sed`/`head`... can handle. Also note that  GNU `sed` has been supporting `-z` for a very long time.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I tried `find /tmp -type f -printf "%T@/%p\0" | sort -zrn | IFS=/ read -rd '' mtime file && printf '%s\0' "$file"`, but it returns nothing.

Comment: It works with `find /tmp/test -type f -printf "%T@/%p\0" | sort -zrn | { IFS=/ read -rd '' mtime file && printf '%s\0' "$file"; }`, but finally I don't really see the problem by using `echo -en "$file\0"`?!

Comment: `echo -e` expands the `\x` sequences, so would break on files with backslashes in their paths.