# using mergecap for set of files

Tags: linux, cron, wireshark

Im trying to use mergecap to merge 15 old pcap files in a folder. I tried to use

```
FILES=($(find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap"  -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lt | tail -15 | awk '{print $8}'))
```

and use mergecap command as `mergecap -w Merge.pcap ${FILES[@]}`  but the mergecap doesnt run when I put it on crontab. Is there any method  to combine these two commands to work properly.

I tried as answer suggested `@l0b0 tried find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap" -print0 | tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | tail -15 | tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | xargs -r0 mergecap -w /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/Merge_"${TAG1}".pcap`
in order to get the name of the oldest file to be merged into the output files name. But it gives gibberish as the file name. Am I doing anything wrong? Following scripts gets me the file names

```
FILES=($(find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap"  -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lt | tail -15 | awk '{print $8}'))

TAG1=$(basename "${FILES[0]}" | sed 's/.pcap//')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh` ([again](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A58138+pcap+ls)):

```
mergecap -w Merge.pcap /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/(D.om[-15,-1])
```

Or with GNU tools:

```
cd /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ &&
  find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pcap' ! -name Merge.pcap -type f  -printf '%T@@%p\0' |
    tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
    sort -n |
    head -n 15 |
    cut -d@ -f2- |
    tr  '\0\n' '\n\0' |
    xargs -r0 mergecap -w Merge.pcap
```

Comment: I am not allowed to install zsh on this system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trick to use [`tail` on NUL-delimited output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75206/3645):

```
find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap" -print0 |
  tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
  tail -n 15 |
  tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
  xargs -r0 mergecap -w Merge.pcap
```

And [you should not parse `ls` output.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: That doesn't sort the list my modification time (as the OP's `ls -t` would imply) before taking the last 15 entries though.

Comment: Im trying to merge the last 15 modified files..