# Convert newlines to null-delimited when using tail

Tags: text-processing, xargs, tail

How can I change the output from `tail` to use null-terminated lines instead of newlines?

My question is similar to this one: [How to do `head` and `tail` on null-delimited input in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75186/how-to-do-head-and-tail-on-null-delimited-input-in-bash), but differs in that I want to do something like:

```
tail -f myFile.txt | xargs -i0 myCmd {} "arg1" "arg2"
```

I am not using `find`, and so cannot use `-print0`

All this is to avoid the error that occurs in xargs:

```
xargs: unmatched double quote;
    by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want that last 10 lines:

```
tail myFile.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -r0i myCmd {} arg1 arg2
```

But with GNU `xargs`, you can also set the delimiter to newline with:

```
tail myFile.txt | xargs -ri -d '\n' myCmd {} arg1 arg2
```

(`-0` is short for `-d '\0'`).

Portably, you can also simply escape every character:

```
tail myFile.txt | sed 's/./\\&/g' | xargs -I{} myCmd {} arg1 arg2
```

Or quote each line:

```
tail myFile.txt | sed 's/"/"\\""/g;s/.*/"&"/' | xargs -I{} myCmd {} arg1 arg2
```

If you want the 10 last NUL-delimited records of `myFile.txt` (but then that wouldn't be a text file), you'd have to convert the `\n` to `\0` before calling `tail` which would mean the file will have to be read fully:

```
tr '\n\0' '\0\n' < myFile.txt |
  tail |
  tr '\n\0' '\0\n' |
  xargs -r0i myCmd {} arg1 arg2
```

**Edit** (since you changed the `tail` to `tail -f` in your question):

The last one above obviously doesn't make sense for `tail -f`.

The `xargs -d '\n'` one will work, but for the other ones, you'll have a buffering problem. In:

```
tail -f myFile.txt | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -r0i myCmd {} arg1 arg2
```

`tr` buffers its output when it doesn't go to a terminal (here, a pipe). I.E., it will not write anything until it has accumulated a buffer full (something like 8kiB) of data to write. Which means `myCmd` will be called in batches.

On a GNU or FreeBSD system, you can alter the buffering behavior of `tr` with the `stdbuf` command:

```
tail -f myFile.txt | stdbuf -o0 tr '\n' '\0' |
  xargs -r0i myCmd {} arg1 arg2
```

Comment: I actually meant to use the -f option on tail, which continuously prints lines as they come in. I didn't think this would matter, but apparently it does. With the -f option your solution doesn't work.

Comment: The `tail -f myFile.txt | xargs -r0i -d '\n' myCmd "{}" "||" "||"` seems to work! Thanks.

Comment: @Lars, sorry, the `-i` option takes an optional argument, so `-i0` would not work. They should all work with `tail -f` except the last one, but beware that because of buffering, there will be a delay before `xargs` gets its input from `tr`. You can change that by running `stdbuf -o0 tr '\n' '\0'` instead of `tr '\n' '\0'`.