# Count nul delimited items in file

Tags: shell-script

I have a shell script which uses `find -print0` to save a list of files to be processed into a temporary file.  As part of the logging I'd like to output the number of files found, and so I need a way to get that count.  If the `-print0` option weren't being used for safety I could use `wc -l` to get the count.

Comment: Related: [How to do `head` and `tail` on null-delimited input in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75186/22565)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Some options:

```
tr -cd '\0' | wc -c

tr '\n\0' '\0\n' | wc -l       # Generic approach for processing NUL-terminated
                               # records with line-based utilities (that support
                               # NUL characters in their lines like GNU ones).

grep -cz '^'                   # GNU grep

sed -nz '$='                   # recent GNU sed, no output for empty input

awk -v RS='\0' 'END{print NR}' # not all awk implementations
```

Note that for an input that  contains data after the last NUL character (or non-empty input with no NUL characters), the `tr` approaches will always count the number of NUL characters, but the `awk`/`sed`/`grep` approaches will count an extra record for those extra bytes.

Comment: I measured these on 5 GB of random data (`head -c 5G /dev/urandom > f`). **Results:** grep 1.7s (same for `grep -Fcz ''`) • tr+wc-c 7.7s • tr+wc-l 7.4s • sed 34.7s • awk 1m11.7s

Comment: @Socowi, YMMV with the implementation and locale. With GNU `awk`, you'll  want to set the locale to `C` (or any that doesn't use multibyte characters), `LC_ALL=C awk ... < f`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I already used `LC_ALL=C` on `sort` where it didn't speed things up, therefore Luckily I have still have the file from before: `LC_ALL=C awk ...` takes 6.7s.

Answer (score 5):

The best method I've been able to think of is using `grep -zc '.*'`.  This works, but it feels wrong to use grep with a pattern which will match anything.

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
perl -0ne 'END {print $.}'
```

or:

```
perl -nle 'print scalar split "\0"'
```

or:

```
perl -nle 'print scalar unpack "(Z*)*", $_'
```

Comment: The first one will count an extra record if there is data after the last NUL. The 2 other ones don't work if the input contains newline characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Oh, my bad. Could you give any improvement?

Comment: I would just keep the first one, and mention the fact that it counts a non-delimited record (contrary to `wc -l`) as a note (as it may be wanted).