# How to show distinct directories on find?

Tags: bash, find

I want to find all directories containing, for example, files named *.txt. but the output must not contain duplicates. How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq
```

This works as follows:

`find . -type f -name "*.txt" -printf '%h\n'` - find all files that end in `*.txt` and print it's directory (`%h`) followed by a newline.

`| sort` - sort the directories

`| uniq` - remove duplicates

Comment: Sir I can't find any article that states the use of %h with printf, please give me a link

Comment: Dear Mr Trovalds Esq.  If you type `man find` at the shell, then type `/%h` you will be taken to the description of the `%h` directive.  If you were to scroll up a page or two from there, you will see that it's under `-printf`.

Comment: this command gives an error on Ubuntu 14, `find: paths must precede expression: <file name>
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]`, but if i use doublel-quotes ("*txt" instead of *.txt) it does not. secondly, it will also list folder name abc.txt, which not as intended

Comment: @edwardtorvalds - good spot, so it does. Thanks for the edits.

Comment: oops we forget to put `-` before name in second line, my apologies

Comment: @edwardtorvalds - fixed :-)

Answer (score 2):

[POSIX compatible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75206/3645) code which should work for *any* filename:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -printf '%h\0' | tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | sort -u | tr '\0\n' '\n\0'
```

Answer (score 2):

A problem can be that directory names can contain newlines, therefore the output from find should be NUL terminated. In order to have readable output pipe the result of sort through `tr`:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -printf '%h\0' | sort -zu | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Any newline in a directory name can probably be determined by looking at the next line, if it starts with `./` it was not a newline in a directory.

Comment: “names that contain newlines” and “readable output” don’t belong in the same paragraph. A pathname of the form `./abcdef/ghi␊./Documents/foo` (where `␊` is a newline) will look like `./abcdef/ghi` followed by `./Documents/foo`.

Comment: your answer create produce same output as `find . -name *.txt -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq`(answer above), but above one is more neat

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -exec dirname {} \; | sort | uniq
```

The `find` + `exec` will get the directory names of all the *.txt files, `sort|uniq` will get you the unique such directories.

Comment: That doesn't work if there are newlines in the diretory names

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `find` and bash

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c \
$'for f; do find \"$f\" -maxdepth 1 -type f  -name \'*.txt\' -printf \'%h\\n\' -quit; done'\
_ {} +
```